# VB.Net Extending Classes and Structures?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a new property for the rectangle structure so that when I create a new rectangle I will be able to specify an extra value(besides the default ones)

For example the default:

```
dim rect as new rectangle(x, y, width, height)
```

I want to be able to declare something like:

```
dim rect as new rectangle (x, y, with, height, another_value as integer)
```

How can I extend the rectangle structure and add a new constructor?

Comment: You can *inherit* a Class and add additional members.  Not a Structure like Rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a class that uses the Rectangle structure.

```
Public Class MyRect
 Public Sub New({use your params for contructor})
   Rect = New Rectangle({initilize from params})
 End Sub
 ....
 Public Property Rect As Rectangle
 'more properties as needed
 ....
```

Then paint your object:

```
Dim _myRectObj As New MyRect({params for your constructor})
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(_myRectObj.Rect, ....)
```